# Почему есть директория node_modules внутри самого модуля и почему там лишь часть модулей от которых этот модуль зависит

Tags: node.js, npm

Мой package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.31.1"
  }
}
```

package.json модуля express:

```
{
  "name": "express",
  "description": "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework",
  "version": "4.18.2",
  "author": "TJ Holowaychuk <tj@vision-media.ca>",
  "contributors": [
    "Aaron Heckmann <aaron.heckmann+github@gmail.com>",
    "Ciaran Jessup <ciaranj@gmail.com>",
    "Douglas Christopher Wilson <doug@somethingdoug.com>",
    "Guillermo Rauch <rauchg@gmail.com>",
    "Jonathan Ong <me@jongleberry.com>",
    "Roman Shtylman <shtylman+expressjs@gmail.com>",
    "Young Jae Sim <hanul@hanul.me>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "expressjs/express",
  "homepage": "http://expressjs.com/",
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "framework",
    "sinatra",
    "web",
    "http",
    "rest",
    "restful",
    "router",
    "app",
    "api"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "accepts": "~1.3.8",
    "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
    "body-parser": "1.20.1",
    "content-disposition": "0.5.4",
    "content-type": "~1.0.4",
    "cookie": "0.5.0",
    "cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
    "debug": "2.6.9",
    "depd": "2.0.0",
    "encodeurl": "~1.0.2",
    "escape-html": "~1.0.3",
    "etag": "~1.8.1",
    "finalhandler": "1.2.0",
    "fresh": "0.5.2",
    "http-errors": "2.0.0",
    "merge-descriptors": "1.0.1",
    "methods": "~1.1.2",
    "on-finished": "2.4.1",
    "parseurl": "~1.3.3",
    "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
    "proxy-addr": "~2.0.7",
    "qs": "6.11.0",
    "range-parser": "~1.2.1",
    "safe-buffer": "5.2.1",
    "send": "0.18.0",
    "serve-static": "1.15.0",
    "setprototypeof": "1.2.0",
    "statuses": "2.0.1",
    "type-is": "~1.6.18",
    "utils-merge": "1.0.1",
    "vary": "~1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "after": "0.8.2",
    "connect-redis": "3.4.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.6",
    "cookie-session": "2.0.0",
    "ejs": "3.1.8",
    "eslint": "8.24.0",
    "express-session": "1.17.2",
    "hbs": "4.2.0",
    "marked": "0.7.0",
    "method-override": "3.0.0",
    "mocha": "10.0.0",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "multiparty": "4.2.3",
    "nyc": "15.1.0",
    "pbkdf2-password": "1.2.1",
    "supertest": "6.3.0",
    "vhost": "~3.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "LICENSE",
    "History.md",
    "Readme.md",
    "index.js",
    "lib/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "mocha --require test/support/env --reporter spec --bail --check-leaks test/ test/acceptance/",
    "test-ci": "nyc --reporter=lcovonly --reporter=text npm test",
    "test-cov": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text npm test",
    "test-tap": "mocha --require test/support/env --reporter tap --check-leaks test/ test/acceptance/"
  }
}
```

Директории которые лежат в /home/alex/sandbox/js/node/1/node_modules/express/node_modules:

debug/  ms/  safe-buffer/

Остальное лежит в /home/alex/sandbox/js/node/1/node_modules

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/folders Читать про hoist/hoisting

Comment: Получается что node js всё старается установить в директорию с наименьшей вложенностью в которой есть node_modules или package.json, но если в этой директории уже есть такой пакет с другой версией, то он установит этот пакет как подмодуль модуля

Comment: спасибо большое за ссылку